# How can I upload an image and form data as well on a single button click?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, file-upload

I am making a practice project in MERN stack and wanted to upload images from react js with the form on single button click, so I needed to call two apis on just one button click. But I am having errors that's why I am unable to upload image and form data as well.

My react js code here:

```
const URL = "http://localhost:2040/add_recipe";
      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("recipe_image", selectedFile);


let config = {
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
     authorization: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")),
    },
  };

axios
  .post(URL, formData, config)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Image uploaded successfully" + response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error while uploading image" + error);
  });
```

and here is my backend api:

```
const Recipe = require("../models/Recipe");
      const fs = require("fs");
      let filePath = "";



const AddRecipe = async (req, res) => {
   if (req.file) {
   filePath = req.file.path;
  }



console.log("filepath: " + filePath);


 let recipee = await Recipe.findOne({ name: req.body.name });
  if (recipee) {
   res.json({ Response: "Recipe already exists!" });
  }  else {
 if (
  req.body.category &&
  req.body.ptime &&
  req.body.name &&
  req.body.noOfPeople &&
  req.body.shortDesc &&
  req.body.recipe
 ) {
  let recipe = await Recipe.create({
    category: req.body.category,
    ptime: req.body.ptime,
    name: req.body.name,
    noOfPeople: req.body.noOfPeople,
    shortDesc: req.body.shortDesc,
    recipe: req.body.recipe,
    avatar: {
      data: fs.readFileSync(filePath),
      contentType: "image/png",
    },
    });


let result = await recipe;
    console.log(filePath + " .......path");
    if (result.name) {
    res.json({ Response: "Recipe added successfully!" });
    } else {
    res.json({ Response: "Recipe not added!" });
    }
    }
   }
  };

  module.exports = { AddRecipe };
```

This is how I called the api with  multer already setup

```
app.post("/add_recipe", verifyToken, upload.single("recipe_image"), AddRecipe);
```

Comment: what error are you facing, can provide the browser console output?

Comment: Error is like: Error while uploading image Network Error....

Comment: Actually is there any other way to upload image with form data... actually I have same code on other pages on same project that page is working fine but this page is not working sometimes I get axios errors and sometimes backend errors like fs.readFileSync(filePath) throwing error

Comment: `authorization: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))` doesn't look right to me.

Comment: no issue in that @Musa

Answer (score 1):

**I found the answer, actually I had to sent all data using FormData inside the axios request and its content-type would be multipart/form-data.**

So, the request should be one because url is same and we can send form data and image as well using FormData append method and on backend we can get image as req.file and data as req.body.*

That's all!